# doing a 'group by', 'sum' and 'count' at one time using panda

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, sum

I have a dataframe that I created from a Data Dictionary format in the following way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( info_closed, columns = [ 'type', 'origQty', 'executedQty' ] )
```

The result is as follows:

```
               type     origQty executedQty
0             LIMIT  0.00362000  0.00362000
1            MARKET  0.00200000  0.00200000
2            MARKET  0.00150000  0.00150000
3            MARKET  0.00150000  0.00150000
4             LIMIT  0.00150000  0.00150000
5             LIMIT  0.00150000  0.00150000
6            MARKET  0.00199500  0.00199500
7             LIMIT  0.00150000  0.00150000
8            MARKET  0.00149800  0.00149800
9             LIMIT  0.00150000  0.00150000
10            LIMIT  0.00149900  0.00149900
11            LIMIT  0.00150000  0.00150000
12           MARKET  0.00149800  0.00149800

[... snip ...]
```

I am trying to create a result in the following manner:

```
           type     origQty executedQty Count
0             LIMIT     13.03   15.01       23
1            MARKET     122.0l  40.00       54
[.. snip ...]
```

Basically, this would be a `group_by (type)` and a `sum( origQty )` and `sum ( origQty )` within each 'type' and a count of records that were use to calculate the values of `sum( origQty )` and `sum (origQty)`

I tried:

```
g = df.groupby(['type'])['origQty', 'executedQty'].sum().reset_index()
```

but the results come out as follows:

```
              type                                            origQty                                        executedQty
0            LIMIT  0.003620000.001500000.001500000.001500000.0015...  0.003620000.001500000.001500000.001500000.0015...
1      LIMIT_MAKER  0.001499000.001500000.001500000.001500000.0014...  0.001499000.001500000.001500000.001500000.0014...
2           MARKET  0.002000000.001500000.001500000.001995000.0014...  0.002000000.001500000.001500000.001995000.0014...
3  STOP_LOSS_LIMIT                                         0.00150000                                         0.00150000
```

Question: what am I doing wrong?

TIA

**ETA:**

Thanks all for the provided solutions!

I ran some but I was still getting this type of output:

```
                                                   origQty                                    

    executedQty
type
LIMIT_MAKER  0.001499000.001500000.001500000.001500000.0014...  0.001499000.001500000.001500000.001500000.0014...
```

The original data was like this (it is a combination of data from the Binance exchange and the ccxt wrapper code. I was attempting to isolate the Binance data ~only~ (whichi is associated with ['info'])

> [{'info': {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'orderId': 2538903025, 'orderListId':
> -1, 'clientOrderId': 'ENDsgXoqtv2ct5jizrfeQe', 'price': '9638.00000000', 'origQty': '0.00150000', 'executedQty': '0.00150000',
> 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '14.45700000', 'status': 'FILLED',
> 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'side': 'BUY',
> 'stopPrice': '0.00000000', 'icebergQty': '0.00000000', 'time':
> 1592879158045, 'updateTime': 1592879162299, 'isWorking': True,
> 'origQuoteOrderQty': '0.00000000'}, 'id': '2538903025',
> 'clientOrderId': 'ENDsgXoqtv2ct5jizrfeQe', 'timestamp': 1592879158045,
> 'datetime': '2020-06-23T02:25:58.045Z', 'lastTradeTimestamp': None,
> 'symbol': 'BTC/USDT', 'type': 'limit', 'side': 'buy', 'price': 9638.0,
> 'amount': 0.0015, 'cost': 14.457, 'average': 9638.0, 'filled': 0.0015,
> 'remaining': 0.0, 'status': 'closed', 'fee': None, 'trades': None},
> {'info': {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'orderId': 2539250884, 'orderListId':
> -1, 'clientOrderId': '5UFBYwDF6b9qJ1UWNsvOYU', 'price': '9653.00000000', 'origQty': '0.00299700', 'executedQty': '0.00299700',
> 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '28.93004100', 'status': 'FILLED',
> 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'side': 'SELL',
> 'stopPrice': '0.00000000', 'icebergQty': '0.00000000', 'time':
> 1592883883927, 'updateTime': 1592884056113, 'isWorking': True,
> 'origQuoteOrderQty': '0.00000000'}, 'id': '2539250884',
> 'clientOrderId': '5UFBYwDF6b9qJ1UWNsvOYU', 'timestamp': 1592883883927,
> 'datetime': '2020-06-23T03:44:43.927Z', 'lastTradeTimestamp': None,
> 'symbol': 'BTC/USDT', 'type': 'limit', 'side': 'sell', 'price':
> 9653.0, 'amount': 0.002997, 'cost': 28.930041, 'average': 9653.0, 'filled': 0.002997, 'remaining': 0.0, 'status': 'closed', 'fee': None,
> 'trades': None}, {'info': {'symbol': 'BTCUSDT', 'orderId': 2539601261,
> 'orderListId': -1, 'clientOrderId': 'testme-15928890617592764',
> 'price': '9633.00000000', 'origQty': '0.00150000', 'executedQty':
> '0.00150000', 'cummulativeQuoteQty': '14.44950000', 'status':
> 'FILLED', 'timeInForce': 'GTC', 'type': 'LIMIT_MAKER', 'side': 'BUY',
> 'stopPrice': '0.00000000', 'icebergQty': '0.00000000', 'time':
> 1592889061852, 'updateTime': 1592889136305, 'isWorking': True,
> 'origQuoteOrderQty': '0.00000000'}, 'id': '2539601261',
> 'clientOrderId': 'testme-15928890617592764', 'timestamp':
> 1592889061852, 'datetime': '2020-06-23T05:11:01.852Z',
> 'lastTradeTimestamp': None, 'symbol': 'BTC/USDT', 'type': 'limit',
> 'side': 'buy', 'price': 9633.0, 'amount': 0.0015, 'cost': 14.4495,
> 'average': 9633.0, 'filled': 0.0015, 'remaining': 0.0, 'status':
> 'closed', 'fee': None, 'trades': None}]

I paired it back by executing the following :

```
info_closed = []
for index,item in enumerate( orders_closed ):
    info_closed.append( item['info'] )
```

The results of what I had is listed above in the first post.

I then ran:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame( final_output, columns = [ 'type', 'origQty', 'executedQty' ] )
```

I am starting to wonder if there is something amiss with the dataframe ... will start looking at this area ...

Comment: Check the datatype's, it might be objects not float try casting to float.

Comment: When summing strings you get concatenation of those strings as you see  in your output.  Change the dtype of Qty columns to numeric using `pd.to_numeric` or `astype` and then sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this, before groupby cast the values to float.

```
df[['origQty', 'executedQty']] = df[['origQty', 'executedQty']].astype(float)

(
    df.groupby(['type'])
        .agg({"origQty": sum, "executedQty": sum, "type": len})
        .rename(columns={'type': 'count'})
        .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this input. Now I just need to get the "count" of each item in the categories. ETA - I stand corrected, I had not followed ALL of your instructions. This did the trick! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I am 99% sure you get the result you want by just doing this:

```
df.groupby(['type'])[['origQty', 'executedQty']].sum()
```